# Tickets places selection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to write an web page where users can select a free seats in a different halls for an events. I prefer not to use flash and make it using only javascript. Is there any library or example that can help me do it?

Edit: I'm asking how to create a client-side UI

Comment: Which database will you use to remember who's selected which seats?

Comment: Is it connected with clients side source code? The major problem may be how will I describe seats position in the halls :(

Comment: @rib.usa: Isn't the OP is more concerned with the UI?

Comment: @Piskvor : ... She needs a database (MySQL, MS SQL, flatfile, whatever) to record who selects what. Users need to know which seats have been taken, and she needs to know the final seating arrangement.  It has nothing to do with UI.

Comment: @rlb.usa: Except @ju is asking about hte UI...

Comment: I'm asking how to create a client-side UI

Comment: @rlb.usa: Yes, yes, I'm aware of that. With separation of tiers, you have HTML+JS at the frontend, showing a nice picture of the auditorium to the user (with free/taken seats), allowing for selection. This interacts with server-side scripts which generate the HTML, and which in turn talk to a database backend. The JS frontend should be isolated from the database backend through abstraction; the database can be MySQL, Oracle 15q or some guy with a filing cabinet, for all the frontend cares. If your UI is tighly coupled with the type of database you're using, that's a pretty strong code smell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a library, but this actually might be a case of using image maps in a semantically-correct, compatible way. The `<map>` and `area` tags are valid even in HTML5, and provide you the convenience of the DOM.

Comment: Is there a way to change area color or put an image where it is in the map?

Comment: I think what you're looking for are absolute divs positioned ontop of the image map, gets a little messy but do-able. You can change the div's transparency level and assign them a background color for a highlighted effect. You can even do rounded corners enough to make the div 'squares' into a circle.

Comment: I proposed image maps because I thought of complex venue shapes, rotated seats etc. and wanted to allow the flexibility of precise clickable areas. However, you could get close enough with regular DOM (a table might be an appropriate, semantic solution as rows and columns have meaning). For basic rotation you could use rotated background images.

Comment: ju, image maps fire events so you could use mouse actions to display price and details on the side and count selected seats and prices on click. However, it is very hard to replace/highlight hovered areas of a map.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you want to go fancier than an image map, you can create a table with one chair per each cell as the physical arrangement looks. You can change each chair's picture according to the state of the seat. You could get fancy  and have the chairs image change to a highlighted color, say yellow, when they hover over it.

Image transitions are done very easily with JQuery, a Javscript library. Here's some resources for rollover images with JQuery : http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2008/04/rollover-images-with-jquery.html

The bad part about this is arranging the chairs, but JQuery is the easy part and it will make your page look fancier and more user friendly. Because with an image map, the actual image can't really change itself to show that seat 4321 has been taken (but you can certainly divulge this information via other means)

Answer (score 1):

I am actually after this too for interfacing to civiEvent, however, this seems to be nebulous 'roll your own' territory for some reason.

The following script + tutorial might give you some mileage:

http://dayg.wordpress.com/2008/04/17/php-101-a-simple-seat-reservation-system/

Please update this thread with whatever you find!